# Pandas Dataframes - Search an integer from one data frame in a string column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

**DF1**

```
                cid          dt        tm    id    distance
2      ed032f716995  2021-01-22  16:42:48    43   21.420561
3      16e2fd96f9ca  2021-01-23  23:19:43   539  198.359355
102    cf092e68fa82  2021-01-22  09:03:14     8   39.599627
104    833ccf05433b  2021-01-24  02:53:08    11   33.168314
```

**DF2**

```
        id            cluster  
0        3                      
1        6             7,8,43  
2       20               1817  
3       25   
4       10  11,13,14,15,9,539
```

I want to search each `id` in `df1` in `cluster` column of `df2`.  The desired output is:

```
                cid          dt        tm    id    distance     cluster
2      ed032f716995  2021-01-22  16:42:48    43   21.420561     7,8,43
3      16e2fd96f9ca  2021-01-23  23:19:43   539  198.359355     11,13,14,15,9,539
102    cf092e68fa82  2021-01-22  09:03:14     8   39.599627     7,8,43 
104    833ccf05433b  2021-01-24  02:53:08    11   33.168314     11,13,14,15,9,539
```

In the above df1 - line 1, since 43 is present in df2, I am including the entire cluster details for  df1 - line 1.

I tried the following:

```
for index, rows in df1.iterrows():
    for idx,rws in df2.iterrows():
        if (str(rows['id']) in str(rws['cluster'])):
            print([rows['id'],rws['cluster']])
```

This looks like working.  However, since the `df2['cluster']` is a string, even if there is a partial match, it is returning the result.  For example, if df1['id'] = 34 and df2['cluster'] has 344,432, etc, it still matches based on 344 and returns a positive result.

I tried another option from SO here:

```
d = {k: set(v.split(',')) for k, v in df2.set_index('id')['cluster'].items()}
df1['idc'] = [next(iter([k for k, v in d.items() if set(x).issubset(v)]), '') for x in str(df1['id'])]
```

However, in the above I am getting an error indicating the length of variable is different between the two datasets.

How do I get the cluster mapped based on exact match of the id column in df1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is split the `cluster`, `explode` it and map:

```
to_map = (df2.assign(cluster_i=df2.cluster.str.split(','))
    .explode('cluster_i').dropna()
    .set_index('cluster_i')['cluster']
)

df1['cluster'] = df1['id'].astype(str).map(to_map)
```

Output:

```
              cid          dt        tm   id    distance            cluster
2    ed032f716995  2021-01-22  16:42:48   43   21.420561             7,8,43
3    16e2fd96f9ca  2021-01-23  23:19:43  539  198.359355  11,13,14,15,9,539
102  cf092e68fa82  2021-01-22  09:03:14    8   39.599627             7,8,43
104  833ccf05433b  2021-01-24  02:53:08   11   33.168314  11,13,14,15,9,539
```

Comment: Thank you.  When I used the code I am getting this error `TypeError: explode() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: @Apricot that's strange. what's your Pandas version?

Comment: sorry my bad.....the code works perfectly....I had too many complications in my production dataset.